# Jenkins screen Reload error

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins for Code analysis. My problem is when I am building project using option "built now". It is not showing me process status. I have to reload page every time I click on any place. In project built, if I am clicking on console output then even in console output is not showing until I am reload browser page. When I started initial I haven't faced this problem. Problem started after project built count is above 50. As I am building daily I am facing this problem after 50 days. 
Details :
**

- jenkins 1.617
- sonarcube 5.1.1
- sonar runner 2.4

**

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to enable auto refresh in jenkins - hope that helps